# Irrational distances, rational area triangles

Tags: elementary-number-theory, triangles

Given any positive integer $n\ge3$ how to show that there are $n$ distinct points in the plane such that

1- the distance between any two points is irrational number and

2- each set of three points determines a non-degenerate triangle whose area is a rational number

Comment: And what has that $\,n\geq 3\,$ to do with this question at all?

Comment: 3 because the question mentions triangles and we need at least three points to form triangles.

Comment: It's not really a combinatorial statement.

Comment: Geometrical then?

Comment: Are you looking for $n$ points?

Comment: I want  to Prove by induction (may be)  that for any  $n\ge3$  there exist $n$ points in the plane such that .....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the points $(x,x^2)$ where $x$ is a non-negative integer. These are lattice points, so the area of any triangle they determine is rational, indeed  of the form $k/2$, where $k$ is an integer.

Now calculate the distance between $(a,a^2)$ and $(b,b^2)$, where $b\gt a$. The square of the distance is 
$$(b-a)^2+(b^2-a^2)^2,$$
which is $(b-a)^2(1+(b+a)^2)$. This cannot be a perfect square, since $1+(b+a)^2$ cannot be: $x^2+1$ is a perfect square only when $x=0$.